# sum of two point distribution converge to infinity almost surely

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems, central-limit-theorem, law-of-large-numbers

**Question:**

$\{X_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ i.i.d.,$P(X_1=-1)=P(X_1=1)=\frac12$.
$S_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n X_k$.
Prove that:

1.$S_n$ converge to infinity almost surely,i.e. $P(\lim_{n\to+\infty}S_n=\infty)=1$;

2.$\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}$ diverge almost surely.

**Attempt:**

1.I have no idea how to prove 'converge to infinity almost surely'.I've tried to prove it in this way:

> If we can show $\forall k\geq 1,\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty P(|S_n|\leq k)<+\infty$,then by Borel-Cantelli,$S_n$ converge to infinity almost surely(since $P(|S_n|\leq k\ i.o.)=0$).

But it turns out that the sum above is $\sum \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ ,so this fails;

2.By computing the characteristic function $E[\exp(it\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}})]\to e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2}$

I know that $\frac{S_n}{\sqrt n}$ converge to $N(0,1)$ in distribution.

Any answer is appreciated.Thanks in advanced.

Comment: This is a first course in probability,so i think maybe LLN,CLT or something like that would work(sadly i can't figure out how to apply them:(

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2063894/symmetric-random-walk-does-not-converge-a-s-using-clt.

Comment: Do you really believe that $\lim S_n = \infty$?. And the second assertion is an immediate corollary of the law of large numbers.

Comment: @Andrew It seems that we just have $S_n$ diverge almost surely...And could you explain how to apply LLT?I'm not sure how to deal with the square root...Thanks a lot.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/595582
Here's an approach to the second by using CLT/characteristic function.

Comment: @shdvt As I said above, your question is precisely a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2063894/symmetric-random-walk-does-not-converge-a-s-using-clt. The key point is that if $S_n \to S$ a.s., then $S_n/\sqrt{n} \to 0$ a.s., so the second part actually implies the first.

Comment: @Prasiortle thanks again,i have no doubt with that now.

Comment: You're very welcome!

Comment: @Prasiortle  i'm wondering how to apply LLT directly to derive 2.(as Andrew suggested)Maybe i'm stuck with something easy...

Comment: I can't myself see how either the (strong) LLN would help, as it would only tell you that $\frac{S_n}{n} \to 0$ a.s.